# how can i use routing in asp.net MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have one problem arrive in my application actually my application is has some functionality like as searching...etc 
When you search with like computer keyword then url is like as below

http://www.example.com/Computer-Company/computer/1

Here computer is keyword But Company is my controller name so i write down some code in my RouteConfig.cs file the code is

```
         routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchResult",
            url: "{Name}-{controller}/{TagName}/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index",            TagName="",Name="",page=""}
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and i have also header and header contain some links 
like as Home when i hover on the home link at that time my url is below

**http://www.example.com/-Home**

so please how can i solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **page** parameter with *, you can send to action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "SearchResult",
  "Company/{*page}",
  new { controller = "Company", action = "Index" }
```

);